# UITableViewCell custom cell with wrong insets after image loading

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following custom UITableViewCell subclass, that renders a rounded image in the imageView attribute:

```
import UIKit

class PicturizedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {

        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
        self.imageView?.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 40, 40)
        self.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = (self.imageView?.frame.width)! / 2
        self.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.imageView?.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.8,
                                                             green: 0.8,
                                                             blue: 0.8,
                                                             alpha: 1.0).CGColor        
    }
}
```

And in my `UITableViewDelegate`, I use this custom cell as bellow (I'm using `Alamofire` to get the image from a web service):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PicturizedTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = (self.patients[indexPath.row] as Patient).name
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "patient-white")

    let _url = (self.patients[indexPath.row] as Patient).photoUrl

    if _url != "" {

        cell.imageView?.af_setImageWithURL(
            NSURL(string: "https:\(_url)")!,
            imageTransition: .CrossDissolve(0.5))
    }

    return cell
}
```

I have correctly set the custom class cell for my cell in the story board, as figure shows:

[image: Custom cell class in storyboard]

The first time that a cell gets rendered, everything works as expected, as figure shows:

[image]

But after that, any loaded or reloaded cell gets its left insets from cell separator and cell label influenced by the size of the image (as if the cell internally is ignoring my new frame for the imageView), as images show:

[image]
[image]

If I force the insets in the `layoutSubviews()` of my custom cell, everything looks fine.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {

    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
    self.imageView?.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 40, 40)
    self.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = (self.imageView?.frame.width)! / 2
    self.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.imageView?.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.8,
                                                         green: 0.8,
                                                         blue: 0.8,
                                                         alpha: 1.0).CGColor

    let _correctedLeftInset = (self.imageView?.frame.width)!
        + ((self.imageView?.frame.origin.x)! * 2)

    self.textLabel?.frame.origin.x = _correctedLeftInset
    self.separatorInset.left = _correctedLeftInset
}
```

But I think this forced left inset is an unnecessary hack because something is missing or wrong. Do you have any idea why?

Let me know if you want more information about the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you test what happens when you move your code from the layoutSubviews to var image : UIImage? { didset {} }? (Dont forget to set the image to the imageView before using self.imageView?.image = image) It seems like the UIImageView properties you set gets overridden after you initialize the cell and set an image.

Comment: What is the implementation of `af_setImageWithURL`? It seems obvious that that one sets the size of the `imageView`, or calls `sizeToFit`, or something like that.

Comment: @fishinear I already tried without this helper function, i.e., receiving the `UIImage` in a callback and setting `imageView.image` from cell by myself. The result is also unaligned.